# Can MongoDB failover in case of disk failure

Tags: mongodb, failover

From online document, it seems only when MongoDB instance is stopped and no heartbeat is detected, then election for failover will happen. But in case of bad disk or bad disk sector and MongoDB write failure to journal or datafile, how will MongoDB response? Will MongoDB instance crash and hence failover can happen after?
Today in MOngoDB bare metal setup, generally how system admin detect and handle disk failure? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since MongoDB 4.2, [Storage Node Watchdog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/monitoring/#storage-node-watchdog) is available in the community servers. From the linked page:

> The Storage Node Watchdog monitors the following MongoDB directories to detect filesystem unresponsiveness:
>
> - The --dbpath directory
> - The journal directory inside the --dbpath directory if journaling is enabled
> - The directory of --logpath file
> - The directory of --auditPath file
>
> If any of the filesystems containing the monitored directories become unresponsive, the Storage Node Watchdog terminates the mongod and exits with a status code of 61. If the mongod is the primary of a replica set, the termination initiates a failover, allowing another member to become primary.

One caveat:

> If any of its monitored directories is a symlink to other volumes, the Storage Node Watchdog does not monitor the symlink target.